# org-capture files entry under wrong datetree

Tags: org-mode

My org-capture setup:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
 '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "@computer")
        "* TODO %?\n %i\n")
   ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/org/gtd.org" "Journal")
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n %i\n")))
```

When I file a note via `org-capture` as a journal entry, it is not saved in the dateree below "Journal" but in the first "2014" node of the document (which does not have a "Journal" parent node).

Does anybody have an idea why this happens or how I can prevent this?

Comment: The Org doc implies that `file+datetree` only takes a file path, not a parent node. So you are seeing the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the only one headline to host a datetree. You can set the DATE_TREE property in the Journal headline, and then there are placed.

But if you want to have more datetrees in the gtd.org file, you should use a file+function target.

**Updated**

I've been developing a solution for this problem taking in consideration multiple DATETREES for the same file and here is my function:

```
(defun test-capture-func ()
  (org-capture-put-target-region-and-position)
  (widen)
  (goto-char 1)
  (search-forward-regexp "^\\*+ Journal")
  (let* ((lvl (org-current-level))
         (org-datetree-base-level (+ 1 lvl)))
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (let* ((date (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute (org-today)))
           (year (nth 2 date))
           (month (car date))
           (day (nth 1 date)))
      (save-restriction
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (org-datetree-find-year-create year)
        (org-datetree-find-month-create year month)
        (org-datetree-find-day-create year month day)
        (goto-char (prog1 (point) (widen)))))
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (org-capture-put :exact-position nil)))
```

But it's a problem the org implementation of the function **org-capture-set-target-location**, needs a small modification I'm going to propose to the org developers. The problem is that when you use the **function** or **file+function** target, it set the **:exact-position** property to **(point)** in the **org-capture-plist**, so you can't append the template as subheading of the current position heading.

The modification is in the function or file+function target, change the line:

```
(org-capture-put :exact-position (point))
```

for:

```
(unless (memq :exact-position org-capture-plist)
  (org-capture-put :exact-position (point)))
```

In this way now, you can set in your function **:exact-position** to nil, as I do in the function above, and then capture puts the templates inside the heading at point.

Comment: The problem I was monkeypatching is solved in the org mode git master. So after comes to packages, the last two lines of the function can be removed.